# Discord.py clone entire server command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a command that Clones the entire server and creates as a backup

Ik this a command

```
@bot.command()

async def copych(ctx, id: typing.Optional[int], *, channame="founders"):

    if id == None:

        chan = ctx.channel

    else:

        chan = bot.get_channel(id=id)

    chan_perm = chan.overwrites

    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=channame, overwrites=chan_perm)
```

But this isn't what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

There is no "command" as such... :) But you can use boto3 and discord to backup the server to an s3 bucket.

```
import discord
import boto3
import json

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_guild_available(guild):
    # Create a backup of the guild data
    backup = {
        "guild_name": guild.name,
        "guild_id": guild.id,
        "guild_member_count": guild.member_count,
        "guild_channels": [],
        "guild_roles": []
    }

    # Add information about the channels in the guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        backup["guild_channels"].append({
            "channel_name": channel.name,
            "channel_id": channel.id,
            "channel_type": str(channel.type)
        })

    # Add information about the roles in the guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        backup["guild_roles"].append({
            "role_name": role.name,
            "role_id": role.id,
            "role_permissions": role.permissions.value
        })

    # Save the backup data to a JSON file
    with open("discord_backup.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(backup, f)

    # Connect to the S3 bucket
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    # Upload the backup file to the S3 bucket
    with open("discord_backup.json", "rb") as data:
        s3.upload_fileobj(data, "my-s3-bucket", "discord_backup.json")

client.run("your-discord-token")
```

And here is a script to restore the server

```
import discord
import boto3
import json

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

    # Connect to the S3 bucket
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    # Download the backup file from the S3 bucket
    with open("discord_backup.json", "wb") as data:
        s3.download_fileobj("my-s3-bucket", "discord_backup.json", data)

    # Load the backup data from the JSON file
    with open("discord_backup.json", "r") as f:
        backup = json.load(f)

    # Create a new Discord server using the backup data
    guild = await client.create_guild(name=backup["guild_name"])

    # Create the channels in the new server
    for channel in backup["guild_channels"]:
        if channel["channel_type"] == "text":
            await guild.create_text_channel(name=channel["channel_name"])
        elif channel["channel_type"] == "voice":
            await guild.create_voice_channel(name=channel["channel_name"])

    # Create the roles in the new server
    for role in backup["guild_roles"]:
        await guild.create_role(name=role["role_name"], permissions=discord.Permissions(role["role_permissions"]))

client.run("your-discord-token")
```

Comment: Ok thank you i will do this